# Trouble running multi-packaged LWJGL project via command-line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, lwjgl

I'm trying to build a small project that I have started. It contains **two** packages, and I am successful at compiling them.

Here is my compilation command:

`javac -d bin -cp .:lib/* pac/game/renderEngine/DisplayManager.java pac/game/engineTester/MainGameLoop.java`

My java compilation skills are a little fuzzy so I apologize if I make a beginner mistake. The process of my compilation is as follows:

- 1) Place all compiled files in my /bin/ directory
- 2) Tell the compiler to look in the /lib/ directory for any .jar files
- 3) Compile `DisplayManager.java` & `MainGameLoop.java`

So, the compilation is successful. However, what I am confused about is running the project. My **main method** is in `MainGameLoop.java` so I will try to run that:

`java -cp .:lib/*:bin -Djava.library.path=native pac.game.engineTester.MainGameLoop`

After numerous Google searches I've come to the above run attempt, but it is not successful.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pac/game/engineTester/MainGameLoop (wrong name: engineTester/MainGameLoop)**

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I *really* don't want to have to use an IDE as I like being able to see exactly how the compilation process works.

Here is the code from my main class:

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DisplayManager.createDisplay();

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            // game logic
            // render
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I would like to emphasize that my two source files are in two separate packages. Thank you for taking the time to look at this and hopefully I will learn something intelligent!